# What are the physical manifestations of the finite-dimensional irreducible non-unitary representations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group:

> "The finite-dimensional irreducible non-unitary representations together with the irreducible infinite-dimensional unitary representations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group, the Poincare group, are the representations that have direct physical relevance."

While the meaning of unitary representations seems clear (over-simplistically, perhaps) reps of symmetry operations corresponding to rotations in the Hilbert space of states (OK?), I can find no elementary description of the physical manifestations ("direct physical relevance") of the finite-dimensional irreducible ***non-unitary*** representations.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: The answer to my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/497456/122952 (and the references therein) give a good explanation.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345106/lorentz-group-representation).

Comment: @NDewolf Many thanks; very helpful and well explained. (I would never have found your answer without your comment.)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Useful refs therein - together with other replies to date that'll keep me busy for a while. Thanks

Comment: NDewolf’s link leads to the following concerning the Poincare Group (PG): "The PG  appears in two different ways in QFT:
• Particles, described by unitary (and hence infinite-dimensional) reps of PG, and
• Fields, described by finite-dimensional (and hence non-unitary) reps of PG."
    Can this be taken (from an ignorant chemist’s viewpoint) as meaning that with PG including translations, particle states include continuous (i.e. unbound) states requiring infinite-D reps, whereas fields described by Fock space have discrete states and finite-D reps?

Answer (score 2):

Indecomposable representations (which are non-unitary and finite dimensional) of Poincaré appear in theories of unstable particles.  It's not an easy topic but was explored in [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1973__19_4_341_0.pdf):

> Raczka, R. "A theory of relativistic unstable particles." Annales de l'IHP Physique théorique. Vol. 19. No. 4. 1973.

Comment: That's a direction that's quite new to me - it looks to be, as you say, not an easy topic, but all grist to the (mental) mill.