# Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking vs Addition of 'Mass terms' by hand

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, bosons

Let consider an $SU(2)$ doublet of bosons $\Phi =(\phi_A, \phi_B)$
which is described by the Lagrangian

$$L = (\partial_{\mu}\Phi)^{\dagger}(\partial_{\mu}\Phi) +a^2 V(\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi)
-\frac{\lambda}{4} (\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi)^2$$

where $a^2, \lambda >0$. this Lagrangian is invariant under a global
$SU(2) \times U(1)$. In order to require the Lagrangian to be invariant
under a local $SU(2) \times U(1)$ transformation we have to replace derivatives by covariant derivatives induced by an $U(1)$ gauge field $B_{\mu}$ and vector bosonic $SU(2)$ gauge field $W=(W^1,W^2,W^3)$.

The continuation is well known: one observes that the field $\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi$
with respect the potential $V:= a^2 V\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi
-\lambda/4 (\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi)^2 $ has non-vanishing VEV (vacuum expectation
value), one chooses an arbitrary non zero vacuum value and breaks the
symmetry in usual way.

One of the main motivations for this SSB (spontaneous symmetry breaking)
mechanism is to explain how the obtained gauge bosons
$Z_{\mu}$ and $W^{1/2}_{\mu}$ become massive bosons and one recognizes this property by observation that after symmetry braking the new Lagrangian
contains terms $$\frac{g_W^{1/2} v^2}{8}W_{\mu}^{1/2} W^{1/2 \mu}\\ \frac{(g_W^2+g_B^2) v^2}{8}Z_{\mu}Z^{\mu}$$ which conventionally regarded as mass terms.

My question is simply is there any reason why one needs to introduce to
principle of spontaneous symmetry breaking in order to obtain massive bosons
(the mass is necessary to explain the short rangeness of the weak force)?

From naive point of view one might also try to extend the initial
Lagrangian 'by hand' with 'mass terms' in gauge bosons. Why is
this approach nowhere studied or compared with the conventional
SSB mechanism which explains the massiveness of the gauge bosons?

What are the advantages? Is it simply easier to develop the theory in consistent way? Are the concrete calculations in most cases easier to perform?

Comment: Adding a mass term to a vector field gives problems when renormalizeing the theory.

Comment: Yes, the renormalization is a great point! I read that a renormalizable theory
stays renormalizable after SSB, this of course seems to a nice feature, while
when 'adding some terms' by hand a rnble theory, may become non-rnble. So it's
hard to 'control', that's the point, right? Is this the 'main' reason why
SSB is prefered in contrast this naive 'adding masses strategy'?

Comment: I would argue that that's one of the possible explanations. A lot has also to do with the underlying symmetries of the theories where the high energy (before SSB) structure is found in nature by experiments. Like the approximate $SU(2)$ isospin symmetry which is naturally broken at lower energies by the mass of the quarks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What goes wrong if we add a mass term for gauge bosons without the Higgs mechanism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296975/)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Almost. The linked question covers the renormalization aspect. One might ask if that's the only reason why SSB is better then 'adding masses'